# GraphQL plugin PyCharm schema error `A schema should have a 'query' operation defined`

Tags: graphql, pycharm

I am currently having a problem with GraphQL plugin for PyCharm.
In GraphQL window in PyCharm I get a Schema error  `A schema should have a 'query' operation defined`. Introspection works and the generated by the plugin schema has type Query defined! wtf?

I am using GraphQL 3.1.2 plugin in PycharmProfessional.
Here is .graphqlconfig file content in case it matters:

```
{
  "name": "Untitled GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "includes" : ["./src/**/*.graphql"],
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://localhost:7777/graphql/",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more info please let me know. How do I solve this problem?[screenshot_from_pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9kQ0.png)